# concatenate arrays with associative keys

Tags: php

I'll let the code speak:

```
$params = array();
$qtyCount = count(array(1,2,3,4,5));
$qtyAr = array(6,7,8,9,10);
$i = 1;
while($i <= $qtyCount){
  $params['quantity_'.$i] .= $qtyAr[$i];
  $i++;
}
```

But when I do this, the last value is missing.

BTW: the values in the qtyCount and qtyAr are bugus... just for example.

Comment: FYI, PHP arrays have zero-based indexes

Comment: The array is zero-based, not 1-based.

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: Why not use a **foreach** loop?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Well it looks like he needs to generate strings according to the index, so a for loop would make more sense, no?

Comment: @WaleedKhan depending on the business logic, an associative array would make much more sense there.

Comment: This is for a paypal cart... it only takes ordered parameters and many parameters may be missing.  Therefore, I check to see if it's empty and if not, assign it the next sequential parameter.

Comment: Tried the foreach loop as well... and the while, do, and everything else.  Just can't get it to retain that last value.

Comment: As for the zero based comment: the ordered sequence has to start at 1 not 0.

Comment: @Patrick Because it's zero-based, the loop should be **$i < $qtyCount**; simply remove the **<=** part.

Comment: Okay, the 0 instead of the 1 is the problem.. it's working, but I still need it to start at 1, not zero in the numbering sequence of the keys...

Comment: Got it... just added 1 to $i.  Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt for a simpler approach:

```
array_walk($qtyAr, function($item, $index) use (&$params) {
    $key = sprintf("quantity_%u", $index);
    $params[$key] = $item;
});
```

It appears that you are starting at the wrong index (1), `$i` should be = 0 as others have pointed out.

Comment: I like your solution best... good thinking.  That's what I was looking to do.  :)

Comment: I edited the answer because the code wasn't working. You'll have to use the `use` keyword to specify you are using the `$params` in the anonymous function, otherwise you won't have access to read or edit its value.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the last element because your unasssociated array starts with `0` and your loop starts with `1`. This is why [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works so much better because it iterates over ALL your elements.

```
$qtyAr = array(6,7,8,9,10);
$i = 1;
foreach($qtyAr as $val) {
    $params['quantity_' . $i] = $val;
    $i++;
}
```